# Unscaling predictor variables from a GLMM using predictorEffect()

Tags: mixed-model, predictor, effects

I'm running GLMMS on scaled and centered data, which has worked well. However, now I am trying to visualize my data using the Effects package and I cannot find a way to backscale my predictor variables.

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
head(raw.data)
X   Year    Site    Species Count   Survey.Night    Disturbed.500
3   2017    MCF001  NoID      1            4          14083.272
6   2017    MCF002  NoID      1            5           8689.328
9   2017    MCF003  NoID      6            6          53869.416
12  2017    MCF004  NoID      43           4          14508.546
15  2017    MCF005  NoID      2            4          25650.885
18  2017    MCF006  NoID      10           4              0
```

I then scaled and centered my data and ran a model similar to the following model (with more terms, but I am only focused on Disturbed term for this example):

```
best.global.500 <- glmer.nb(Count ~ Disturbed.500 + offset(log(Survey.Night)) + (1|Site),
                               data = scaled.data)
summary(best.global.500)
```

Now, I found the best way to visualize my model was using the Effects package. I run

```
dist.500 <- predictorEffect("Disturbed.500", best.global.500, se = list(type="pointwise", level = 0.95))
dist.500.plot <- plot(dist.500, main = "A", lines = list(col = "black", lwd=3),
                      axes = list(x = list(rug = TRUE, 
                                           rotate = 0, 
                                           cex = 2.5,
                                           Disturbed.500 = list(lab=expression(paste("Disturbed Landcover (m"^"2",")")))),
                                  y = list(type = "link", 
                                           lab = "Bat Activity (log-link)",
                                           cex = 2.5, 
                                           lim = c(-2,6))),
                      lattice=list(key.args=list(space = "none",
                                                 corner = c(1,1),
                                                 columns=1,
                                                 border=TRUE,
                                                 fontfamily="serif",
                                                 cex=1.05,
                                                 cex.title=2)))
dist.500.plot
```

[image]

This figure is fine, except that my predictor variable, Disturbed Landcover, is still scaled and centered, which makes interpretation quite difficult. So I went through Effects vignette and found that you can transform the x variable using **transform = list(trans =, inv =)** and I tried something like this:

```
dist.500 <- predictorEffect("Disturbed.500", best.global.500, se = list(type="pointwise", level = 0.95))

unscale <- function(x) ((x * sd(raw.data$Disturbed.500))+mean(raw.data$Disturbed.500))

scale.data <- function(x) (x-mean(raw.data$Disturbed.500))/sd(raw.data$Disturbed.500)

dist.500.plot <- plot(dist.500, main = "A", lines = list(col = "black", lwd=3),
                      axes = list(x = list(rug = TRUE, 
                                           rotate = 0, 
                                           cex = 2.5,
                                           Disturbed.500 = list(transform = list(trans = unscale,
                                                                                 inverse = scale.data),
                                                                ticks = list(at=(c(-100,0,1000,10000,200000))),
                                                                lab=expression(paste("Disturbed Landcover (m"^"2",")")))),
                                  y = list(type = "link", 
                                           lab = "Bat Activity (log-link)",
                                           cex = 2.5, 
                                           lim = c(-2,6))),
                      lattice=list(key.args=list(space = "none",
                                                 corner = c(1,1),
                                                 columns=1,
                                                 border=TRUE,
                                                 fontfamily="serif",
                                                 cex=1.05,
                                                 cex.title=2)))
dist.500.plot
summary(dist.500.plot)
```

I thought that would work, but it just generates the same graph as before. Does anyone have any insight on how to unscale predictor variables to use them for a predictorEffect plot??